# Joomla invalid token message

Tags: joomla, token

since this new EU cookies privacy law came out, i had to implement a plugin on my website that block all cookies on my website till the user accept.
The problem here is that some users dont accept the cookies but even so they try to login, and then they get that blank page with invalid token message. Theres nothing good on that invalid token message, i would like to redirect those users who get this message to a ustom page, i managed to find the code but i mjust dont know how to change it to redirect the user, heres the code:

```
function login()
    {
        // Check for request forgeries
        JRequest::checkToken('request') or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );

        global $mainframe;

        if ($return = JRequest::getVar('return', '', 'method', 'base64')) {
            $return = base64_decode($return);
            if (!JURI::isInternal($return)) {
                $return = '';
            }
        }
```

i believe i have to use the "header: location" thing but just dont know how to implement that on the current code.

Hope someone can point me for a clue

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Joomla redirect function.

```
function login()
    {
        // Check for request forgeries
        if(!JRequest::checkToken('request')) {
            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
            $app->redirect('index.php', 'Invalid token. You must accept cookies in order to use this website'); 
        }

        global $mainframe;

        if ($return = JRequest::getVar('return', '', 'method', 'base64')) {
            $return = base64_decode($return);
            if (!JURI::isInternal($return)) {
                $return = '';
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks so much Marko, that worked, but i really would like to redirect  the user to a custom page, where i can create a nice warning like a custom "404 page not found". By the way, i noticed you removed the jexit code, does the form will still be secure? Thanks for your time

Comment: You can set any link to which you want to redirect, if you start it with `http`, it will redirect to an external page, so why not just change it to lead to your custom page? i removed `jexit`, since that's like a `die()` but with clearing session etc

Comment: Ok i will try to play with your code and reply back with the results. Thanks so much Marko.

Comment: Sorry for delay, it worked like a charm. One headache less. Thanks so much for your help!!